# Decimal point aligned columns with two pairs of parens for uncertainty

Tags: tables, siunitx, dcolumn

I'm trying to decimal point align my columns. I'm using numbers in parens at the end of a number to represent the uncertainty, and in one case I have two sources of uncertainty broken out, so I have two pairs of parens. I've tried using both `dcolumn` (with `d` and with various ways of specifying a new column type drawn from similar questions) and `siunitx` (with `S` and various combinations of adding brackets around the parens or using new command to add parens with brackets around them) and everything I've tried has failed. Here is the code I would like to work:

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{easy-todo}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines



\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|SSS}
A&36&50.0007(6)(45)&50.0008(9)&50.0010(3) \\
B&37&1050.07(6)(45)&1050.08(9)&1050.10(3) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

And in the output you can see the first column following the vertical separator is simply missing, though it seems to have worked for the other two columns.

[image]

Comment: You've forgotten the first  `$` sign in the 3rd column.

Comment: thanks, I fixed that, the output is unchanged

Comment: Actually, by default, siunitx types numerical inputs in math mode, so you should have no `$`  in the last three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following ouput with a workaround (definition of two commands `\leftparen` and `\rightparen`):

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{easy-todo}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

\let\leftparen(
\let\rightparen)


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|SSS}
A&36&50.0007(6)\leftparen45\rightparen&50.0008(9)&50.0010(3) \\
B&37&1050.07(6)\leftparen45\rightparen&1050.08(9)&1050.10(3) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]